# Tex Live installation fails on Windows 10 if username contains non-ascii character

Tags: errors, texlive, installing, windows, texlive2022

I tried installing `Tex Live` on a typical `Windows 10` system. `64-bit Intel` with more than `100GB` to spare. Less than a minute into the installation, the installer ended. Surprised that it ended so early since I opted for a full installation, I examined the logs and found an error had occurred. The path names in the logs were unlegible. I soon realized that the username is not fully composed of ascii characters and that probably caused issues. Unfortunately this is a school computer so I cannot change the username. Is there a way I can install Tex Live on this computer without creating a new user or changing the username?

Comment: {assuming the bug is indeed caused by the non-ASCII username, I didn't test} Sounds difficult, this bug is definitely not in high priority for the developers. (that having said as a workaround maybe try another TeX distribution? Or preinstall/change the install location to something like USB/a different folder)

Comment: ask on the texlive mailing list https://www.tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live. But you will have to give more details like the user name and the error message.